# $unset not working on array of objects?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like below:

```
{
   title: "whatever",
   answers: [
      {id: 10, question: ObjectId("54380350a52147000aad4e9b")},
      {id: 13, question: ObjectId("54380350a52147000aad4e9c")},
      {id: 33}
   ]
}
```

I'm have attempted to unset the `question` attribute using the commands below:

```
db.participants.update({}, {$unset: {"answers.question": ""}}, {upsert: false, multi:true} )
```

and

```
db.participants.update({}, {$unset: {"answers.question": 1}}, {upsert: false, multi:true} )
```

Both of these spit out: `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 628795, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })` when completed, but no documents are updated (as the message suggests).  Any idea why my update isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update is not working because `answers` is an array. So you should use the positional operator:

```
db.participants.update({ 'answers.question': { $exists: true } }, { $unset: { 'answers.$.question': '' } }, { upsert: false, multi: true });
```

However it updates only one item in the array. This is a limitation of MongoDB, see [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server-1243).

You can use a `forEach` to iterate through the items of the array:

```
db.eval(function () {

    db.participants.find({ 'answers.question': { $exists: true } }).forEach(function (participant) {

        participant.answers.forEach(function (answer) {

            delete answer.question;
        });

        db.participants.update({ _id: participant._id }, { $set: { answers: participant.answers } });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, thanks for explaining why it wasn't working.  Ended up using a modified version of your first update that matched on a condition that would return each array element and then used the positional operator.  Seemed a bit simpler than the `forEach` solution.

Comment: Your query with the positional operator still updates only one item in the array. The condition doesn't affect the update in that case.

Comment: Oh you're right.  Bummer, that seems pretty complex to clear out a value.